Latex error when importing a stacking regression table from STATA
I am having an issue stacking stata regression outputs in latex. I am showing below the first panel of the table only. I have removed the two middle and bottom panels.
Here is the Stata code, which runs smoothly in Stata:
esttab reg1noc_correct reg1yesc_correct reg1noc_non_correct reg1yesc_non_correct using first.tex, replace f prehead(\begin{tabular}{l*{@M}{r}} \toprule) se(3) star(* .1 ** .05 *** .01) keep(tmt2) varlabels(tmt2 "Treated") stats(cmean beta_scaled controls N r2, label("Control mean" "Scaled Effect" "Covariates" "Obs." "R-squared")) booktabs noobs nonotes collabels(none) alignment(D{.}{.}{-1}) mtitles("Pub knowledge" "Non-pub knowledge") compress nogaps varwidth(20) postfoot(\bottomrule \end{tabular})

Then, I use the following code to import the first panel "first.tex" in my main.text file in Overleaf:
\begin{table}[!htbp]
   %\caption{Effects of pub knowledge}
   %\centering
   \input{"first.tex"}
\end{table}

The following error message occurs:
"The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}."
My preambule looks like so:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\def\xstrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}} %for tables
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

When I look into the "first.tex" file, I have in red the following lines:
\midrule
Treated             &    1.061\sym{}&    1.058\sym{}&  -0.0174         &   0.0513         \
Even when I change the Overleaf to code to simply:
\input{"first.tex"}

I still get the same error message.
Can anyone help me out here? I can't figure out what mistake I am making since Stata didn't  flag any error.
Best,
Guyle

Try it without the quotes, and .tex is optional.

Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you replace \input{"first.tex"} with \input first?

Thank you David and Mico, still the same error message.

Undefined control sequence.
Below is the error message:
‪./first.tex, 5‬
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more
l.5 Treated             &    1.061\sym
{}&    1.058\sym{}&  -0.0174    ...

In the first.text file, I have these two lines in red, but I cannot figure out what is wrong here: \midrule
Treated             &    1.061\sym{}&    1.058\sym{}&  -0.0174         &   0.0513         \

From the log file, copy the part after "Learn more": l.5 Treated & 1.061\sym {}& 1.058\sym{}& -0.0174.  Edit that into your post, and make sure the line break here matches the line break that you copied from.

Hi Teepeemm, here are the lines after "learn more": l.5 Treated             &    1.061\sym
{}&    1.058\sym{}&  -0.0174    ...
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
43967 strings out of 475237
974305 string characters out of 5764570
1950244 words of memory out of 5000000
64476 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
577286 words of font info for 111 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
84i,14n,87p,1593b,1269s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

My guess would be that \sym is undefined. But we would have to see the contents of "first.tex" to be sure. If it is not defined there, maybe you can try to add something like \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

Hi Pieter, you were right. It worked now. Thank you very much!
